# CakePHP Js Helper - Update 3 Dropdown menus dynamically

Tags: ajax, cakephp, drop-down-menu

i'm using CakePHP 2.6.1

I have a cakephp form to handle accesses with these 3 dropdown menues:
location->facility->department

I want them to be dynamic populated and so i followed this tutorial http://marnienickelson.com/2014/10/11/dynamic-dropdowns-with-cakephp-2-x/

It works well, except one little problem. If i change the "location", the "facility" Dropdown menu is filled correctly, but the "department" menu stays blank...

My AccessesController.php

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Access->create();
        if ($this->Access->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The access has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The access could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $titles = $this->Access->Title->find('list');
    $locations = $this->Access->Facility->Location->find('list');
    $systems = $this->Access->System->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('titles', 'locations', 'facilities', 'departments', 'systems'));
}
```

My get_by_location.ctp (and i have an equal file called get_by_facility.ctp)

```
<?php foreach ($facilities as $key => $value): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And at the end of my add.ctp

```
<?php
$this->Js->get('#AccessLocationId')->event('change', 
$this->Js->request(array(
    'controller'=>'facilities',
    'action'=>'getByLocation'
    ), array(
    'update'=>'#AccessFacilityId',
    'async' => true,
    'method' => 'post',
    'dataExpression'=>true,
    'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
    'isForm' => true,
    'inline' => true
    ))
    ))
);

$this->Js->get('#AccessFacilityId')->event('change', 
$this->Js->request(array(
    'controller'=>'departments',
    'action'=>'getByFacility'
    ), array(
    'update'=>'#AccessDepartmentId',
    'async' => true,
    'method' => 'post',
    'dataExpression'=>true,
    'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
    'isForm' => true,
    'inline' => true
    ))
    ))
);
```

?>

I know the second event'change' isnt recognized and thats why my 3rd dropdown stays blank... Is there an other event then 'change'? Or could i put these two ajax requests in one?

Comment: You have to put the both in one , the two requests in one.

Comment: Ok i can put the requests together, but then Js->get is just looking for LocationID ?? Cakephp Docs says: _Set the internal ‘selection’ to a CSS selector. The active selection is used in subsequent operations until a new selection is made_ I have to watch the LocationID AND FacilityID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Blog helped me alot [Euromarks blog](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/)

I just changed my get_by_location.ctp file:

```
    <?php
if (!empty($facilities)) {
    echo '<option value="">' . __('pleaseSelect') . '</option>';
    foreach ($facilities as $k => $v) {
        echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . h($v) . '</option>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<option value="0">' . __('noOptionAvailable') . '</option>';
}
```

So if first dropdown is changed, the second one will display "please select".