# Ajax Menu in CakePHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cakephp

I'm learning CakePHP and I need to make an AJAX menu (a menu which doesn't reload the page once you click on the links).

I could easily do that with JavaScript with something like:

```
function loadPage(page) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", page, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

and then call it for each button on the menu and its corresponding page, with only the HTML code that would go in the "container" id'd div:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("homeButton").onclick = function() { loadPage("home.html"); }
    document.getElementById("newsButton").onclick = function() { loadPage("news.html"); }
    document.getElementById("aboutButton").onclick = function() { loadPage("about.html"); }
    document.getElementById("registerButton").onclick = function() { loadPage("contact.html"); }
}
```

Well now, since I'm not very familiarized with the CakePHP framework and how it works the HTTP requests i'm having some trouble.

How would you do that in CakePHP?

I appreciate the help, good day.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28456650/1531971

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short answer: `ajax` layout is your friend!

Yes, you can do that with CakePHP. (You did not mention which CakePHP you are using so I will assume 2.x)

CakePHP uses the concept of `layouts` to render the HTML *around* a page, like the `doctype` declaration, the navigation menu and other things common to all HTML pages in your app.

When doing AJAX calls you want to get only the *content* of the page without this surrounding layout. To accomplish that you need to use an empty layout or the default `ajax.ctp` layout that CakePHP provides for you.

This is the relevant documentation from CakePHP 2.x about [layouts](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts) and it talks a bit about `ajax` layout as well.

In short, in your controller you need to set the layout to `ajax` for the pages that you want to have rendered via ajax.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using CakePHP 3.5.

About the layouts, the system I'm trying to work on already has the layouts set up and menu links executing the "index" action from the Controller.

So should I set the layout to ajax like `$this->layout = 'ajax'` in the index action and put the content I want to update in this ajax.ctp file?

Comment: Here is the link for [CakePHP 3.x](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#layouts) you do need to read that page about layouts. The special `ajax` layout is actually empty so putting stuff in it will break it. Remember, layout is not the content is the stuff that goes _around_ your content.